# date splitting using substring function

Tags: sql-server, substring, charindex

I have a date in a string format I am trying to split this column into (day month year)

[image: input data]

so I tried to work with charindex and substring but I always end up having a problem with  the month

[image: current out_put]

here is the script I used to split DD MM YYYY

```sql
select substring(substring([TRANSACTION_EFFECTIVE_DATE], 
  charindex(' ',[DATE])+1,charindex(' ',[DATE])
  -(charindex([TRANSACTION_EFFECTIVE_DATE], 1, 1)-10)),1 , 2) AS DD
FROM Date
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates as (regional) strings in the first place? And is your column named `DATE` or `TRANSACTION_EFFECTIVE_DATE`? Please build a working [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle) instead of taking screenshots, and use a tag to specify what version of SQL Server you're using.

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making the string manipulation a whole lot more complicated than it has to be - as long as you're using French as your language, you can parse the date as is if you just remove the weekday name. That doesn't mean you should have been storing this information as regional and non-standard strings in the first place - why aren't you storing dates using a `date` data type?

```
SET LANGUAGE Français;

SELECT DateColumn, HowItShouldHaveBeenStored = TRY_CONVERT(date, 
  SUBSTRING(DateColumn, CHARINDEX(' ', DateColumn), 64), 106)
FROM dbo.DateTable;
```

Output:

| DateColumn | HowItShouldHaveBeenStored |
| --- | --- |
| vendredi 23 juillet 2021 | 2021-07-23 |
| mardi 30 novembre 2021 | 2021-11-30 |
| mercredi 10 février 2021 | 2021-02-10 |
| lundi 23 août 2021 | 2021-08-23 |
| mardi 13 avril 2021 | 2021-04-13 |
| samedi 3 juillet 2021 | 2021-07-03 |
| jeudi 3 février 2022 | 2022-02-03 |
| jeudi 13 mai 2022 | 2022-05-13 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d935d554d5e3944e942bbfc2c01b4ee)

If you really need the individual date parts:

```
SET LANGUAGE Français;

;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT DateColumn, d = TRY_CONVERT(date, 
    SUBSTRING(DateColumn, CHARINDEX(' ', DateColumn), 64), 106)
  FROM dbo.DateTable
)
SELECT DateColumn, HowItShouldBe = d, 
  DD   = DAY(d),
  MM   = MONTH(d),
  MMM  = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, d), 3),
  YYYY = YEAR(d)
FROM src;
```

Output:

| DateColumn | HowItShouldBe | DD | MM | MMM | YYYY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vendredi 23 juillet 2021 | 2021-07-23 | 23 | 7 | jui | 2021 |
| mardi 30 novembre 2021 | 2021-11-30 | 30 | 11 | nov | 2021 |
| mercredi 10 février 2021 | 2021-02-10 | 10 | 2 | fév | 2021 |
| lundi 23 août 2021 | 2021-08-23 | 23 | 8 | aoû | 2021 |
| mardi 13 avril 2021 | 2021-04-13 | 13 | 4 | avr | 2021 |
| samedi 3 juillet 2021 | 2021-07-03 | 3 | 7 | jui | 2021 |
| jeudi 3 février 2022 | 2022-02-03 | 3 | 2 | fév | 2022 |
| jeudi 13 mai 2022 | 2022-05-13 | 13 | 5 | mai | 2022 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b0b2e3d1b88a624d8d81dbb879d589d)

Answer (score 0):

If the spaces are replaced by dots then the [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) function can be used to get the 4 parts.

> ```
> SELECT TRANSACTION_EFFECTIVE_DATE
> , PARSENAME(REPLACE(TRANSACTION_EFFECTIVE_DATE,' ','.'), 1) AS TR_Year
> , PARSENAME(REPLACE(TRANSACTION_EFFECTIVE_DATE,' ','.'), 2) AS TR_Month
> , PARSENAME(REPLACE(TRANSACTION_EFFECTIVE_DATE,' ','.'), 3) AS TR_Day
> , PARSENAME(REPLACE(TRANSACTION_EFFECTIVE_DATE,' ','.'), 4) AS TR_Weekday
> FROM YourTable;
> ```

> | TRANSACTION_EFFECTIVE_DATE | TR_Year | TR_Month | TR_Day | TR_Weekday |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | vendredi 23 juillet 2021 | 2021 | juillet | 23 | vendredi |
> | mardi 30 novembre 2021 | 2021 | novembre | 30 | mardi |
> | mercredi 10 février 2021 | 2021 | février | 10 | mercredi |
> | lundi 23 août 2021 | 2021 | août | 23 | lundi |
> | mardi 13 avril 2021 | 2021 | avril | 13 | mardi |
> | samedi 3 juillet 2021 | 2021 | juillet | 3 | samedi |
> | jeudi 3 février 2022 | 2022 | février | 3 | jeudi |
> | jeudi 13 mai 2022 | 2022 | mai | 13 | jeudi |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=831bf0651a87c5fb0ac74b67479e77c0)*

*Side-note.  Please consider storing that data as a DATE datatype.*